# DropNet Chunked Upload

Tags: c#, dropbox, dropnet, large-file-upload

The current version of DropNet (1.8.2.0) seems to be handling the REST portion of things fine, but when I call the final CommitChunkedUpload to complete the upload, I get a dropbox error indicating that the path parameter was in the wrong format.

```
client.CommitChunkedUpload(upload, "/" + FolderName + "/" + FileName, true);
```

Leaving off the folder or changing where I want the file to be saved does not resolve things. If I leave off the filename then it tries to save the folder as a file with no contents but does not throw the error.

Am I missing something in the syntax?

Comment: Can you post the full error response as well as what your parameters evaluate to?

Comment: I will work on it, but unfortunately the actual piece of software is designed for a server environment and cannot be installed and run successfully on my development machine, so there is not a simple way to debug it. I may end up with a test app that I can run on the development machine just to take advantage of the debugging till I get this sorted out.